# Inverse $\mathcal{Z}$ transform of $\frac{1}{z^2(z+1)}$ without delta function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, transformation, z-transform

While finding inverse $\mathcal{Z}$ transform of $\frac{1}{z^2(z+1)}$ i split it into three parts using partial fractions:

$$\frac{a}{z} + \frac{b}{z^2}+\frac{c}{z+1}$$

and so answer comes as

$$a \delta(n-1) + b\delta(n-2) + c (-1)^{n-1} H(n+1) $$

where $\delta$ is delta function and $H$ is step function

Now I checked with online calculator tool [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+Z+transform+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseZTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%221%2F%28z%5E2%28z-1%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseZTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22z%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22InverseZTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22n%22)

It gives answer as $(-1)^{n+1} H(n-3)$. I cannot understand where the $\delta$ went away? And how can my solution arrive at the one given in online calculator, that is, how can I get rid of delta function in my solution

I have verified that online calculator gives correct result also as its $\mathcal{Z}$ transform comes as stated above.

Comment: hint: what are $a,b,c$ and what is the value of $H(n-3)$ on $n=1,2$?

Comment: @user619894 yes they get cancelled!

Answer (score 1):

We have $$X(z) = \frac{1}{z^2(z+1)}= \frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{z+1} - \frac{1}{z}$$Let $$X(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n}$$Also $\mathcal{Z}\{\delta[n - 1]\} =  \frac{1}{z}$ and $\mathcal{Z}\{\delta[n - 2]\} =  \frac{1}{z^2}$. Note that $$\mathcal{Z}\{a^{n-1}u[n-1]\} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a^{n-1}z^{-n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a}(\frac{z}{a})^{-n} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a}(\frac{z}{a})^{-n} - \frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{a}\times\frac{1}{1 - \frac{a}{z}} - \frac{1}{a} = $$ $$\frac{1}{a}\times \frac{a}{z-a} = \frac{1}{z-a}$$Here $a = -1$ and we have $$\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\{X(z)\} = -\delta[n-1] + \delta[n-2] + (-1)^{n-1}u[n-1]$$